# "admit to" or "admit"

Tags: prepositions

- She admitted to making a mistake.
- She admitted making a mistake.

In first sentence the preposition ***to*** has been used, while in second it is not. Please tell me what are the differences between them. If both are correct, when to use ***admit to + gerund*** and when to use **admit + gerund**.

Thanks!

Comment: In the second sentence, *admit* always takes the *-ing* form, that's why the infinitive isn't used.

Answer (score 4):

This is a construction where usage has changed over time. A century ago, the preposition ***to*** would almost *never* be included in OP's example, but today it usually *would* be...

[[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jz7Kx.png)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he%20admits%20having%2Che%20admits%20to%20having&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20admits%20having%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20admits%20to%20having%3B%2Cc0)

Having said that, I don't think many native speakers would consciously recognize the prepositionless form as "dated". I only just discovered this significant usage shift<sup>1</sup> myself - because the question piqued my interest, *and* because it's now quite easy to investigate such matters using online corpora.

So it's probably better for OP to stick to #1 because it'll make him sound "more like a native speaker". But rather curiously, hardly any native speakers would notice anything "odd" if he used #2.

---

Note that syntactically you *admit [to] **something***. The *thing* admitted [to] must be a ***noun*** (note that *gerunds* are "verb forms functioning as nouns"), so there's no role for an *infinitive* verb form here.

---

<sup>1</sup> I've now realised the particular text I chose for my chart rather overstates the shift - but [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=admitted%20making%2Cadmitted%20to%20making&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cadmitted%20making%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cadmitted%20to%20making%3B%2Cc0) and [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=admitted%20the%20crime%2Cadmitted%20to%20the%20crime&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cadmitted%20the%20crime%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cadmitted%20to%20the%20crime%3B%2Cc0) both show even more clearly what a "recent and upcoming" usage the preposition represents.

Answer (score -1):

Both are commonly used.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/admit) uses the version without *to*:

> *admitted* making a mistake

The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/2589;jsessionid=762AA4CD8BCECEDF34609B7ED8CD6EF6?redirectedFrom=admit#eid) also cites several examples and notes "often with *to*" but for definitions other than the one you're using (e.g. he was admitted to the theatre).

[This Google Ngram chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=admitted%2C%20admitted%20to&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cadmitted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cadmitted%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Badmitted%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAdmitted%20to%3B%2Cc0) shows that most instances of "admitted" omit "to."

Based on these sources, I'd recommend just using the version without *to*, especially if it's easy to remember, but not worry too much about it.

Comment: this is a bad ngram, not comparing like with like.  Searching for "admit" includes all instances of the verb, including those with *to*, those with no following verb (e.g. "I admit that I..."), or even the meaning of "let in" as in "They only admit guests with tickets" etc.

Comment: @Some_Guy sure, the ngram should be taken with a big grain of salt and merely supplements the answer rather than providing the authoritative source.

Comment: I'm not sure that it does supplement it, I think it's so misleading that it detracts from it for the reasons I outlined. Because of all the other information the query encompasses, it provides no information at all (or least no correct information) on which structure is more common between [admit] + gerund vs. [admit] to + gerund.